# Trouble with tutorial on getting started with Webassembly

Tags: bash, webassembly

I'm following the guide [here](http://webassembly.org/getting-started/developers-guide/) for creating a Hello World wasm application (Mac OS). I followed everything to a T, and am sure `git` and `python` are in my `PATH`, and 90% sure `cmake` is in my path. The installations were long but went fine. When I type the command `emcc hello.c -s WASM=1 -o hello.html` into my terminal, however, I receive the message `-bash: emcc: command not found`. Tried to `sudo` it too.

Not sure what the issue is. I'm obviously extremely green to wasm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [page you linked](http://webassembly.org/getting-started/developers-guide/) shows the command needed to add relevant environment variables and directory entries to PATH.  On Mac the command would be:

`source ./emsdk_env.sh`

Comment: I ran that when prompted.